# Syntax error when I try to insert my loop into an unordered list?

Tags: php, theme-development, loop, html

I am very new in PHP and WordPress development and I have the following problem trying to insert some HTML code into the posts loop.

I tried something like it:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    <ul>
    // Start the Loop.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        /*
         * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
         * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
         * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
         */

        <li>
        get_template_part('contentArchive', get_post_format());
        </li>

    endwhile;
    </ul>


    endwhile;
?>
```

As you can see I want an unordered list (the `< ul>`tag) and into it I want put the one list element (the `< li>` tag) for each iteration of the `while` cycle, but Aptana Studio give me a syntax error message on the `<ul>` and on the `<li>`

Why? Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding HTML code to your file, you're adding invalid PHP.

To recap, in PHP everything between `<?php` and `?>` is PHP code.

So this is valid PHP:

```
<?php echo 'hello world';! ?>
```

This is also valid:

```
<b><?php echo 'hello world'; ?></b>
```

This is not valid:

```
<?php <b> echo 'hello world'; </b> ?>
```

Why? Because  is invalid PHP. It's a valid HTML tag yes, but you didn't put it in HTML, you put it in-between the  tags so it's PHP code, and it isn't valid PHP code.

## Sidenotes

- You're not indenting your code correctly. Any good editor will auto-magically do it for you, PHPStorm has a reformat option, Sublime auto-indents as you type, save yourself time and effort and use an editor that does it for you. Indenting makes your code easier to read, and bugs easier to spot
- Use brackets instead of shorthand, e.g. `if( this ) { do that }`, it has wider support among editors and checkers. It's too easy to add stray `endwhile;` statements ( your original code has 1 while loop, but you close it twice, this makes no sense and only serves to confuse ). If you use `{` and `}` a good editor will automatically type the closing bracket for you and indent it accordingly.

So in conclusion, your code should look more like this:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        get_template_part( 'contentArchive', get_post_format() );
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Changes:

- Used echo to print out the html
- removed extraneous blank lines and converted to tabs
- fixed indenting
- Used braces instead of PHP shorthand syntax
- removed the trailing PHP closing tag, closing tags are unnecessary at the end of a PHP file if the last thing is PHP code

Answer (score 2):

You are including HTML elements without closing the php tags. Also, the last one should be `endif`, not `endwhile`.

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <ul>

    <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
    ?>

        <li>
            <?php 
                get_template_part('contentArchive', get_post_format());
            ?>
        </li>

    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>

    </ul>

    <?php
        endif;
?>
```